# how to bisect a line segment(line can be vertical or horizontal) perpendicular in canvas using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2). line can be drawn horizontal or vertical.i am able to find out bisecting point for bisecting a line sigment. i am not able to draw a perpendicular line if line is vertical or line is at different angles.can any body help with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to find the mid of the segment

```
mid = ((x1+x2)/2 , (y1+y2)/2)
```

Then you just need a line through passing through that point, either horizontal or vertical that can be found by understand the slope of original line, typically a slope of horizontal line is to be zero.

Comment: Thanks for giving answer. and i can able to find out mid point of the line. but i need to draw a line through that point. how can i draw a line. how to draw a line exactly 90deg at any angle of the line.

Comment: @sekharchintamani it depends how how you axis are placed, lets say your horizontal axis is X and vertical is Y, and you original segment is horizotnal (which means the y values will remain same), so to draw a line perpendicular means it draw it vertical (which means you x remains same) and that is the x value of the mid-point, so only y value changes. This y value now depends on how big you want to line, so start incrementing the y value keeping the x same, you'll get the required line.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr767267.